# Why can't I change what bone I'm looking at in Weight Paint?

Tags: bones, weight-painting

When I select a bone, it shows up as selected, but the weight data being shown to me does not change to match that of the bone I selected.

Answer (score 1):

When you're in weight paint mode, the mesh is the active object, so, to change the bone you want to paint you have to select the corresponding vertex group.

As a shortcut, you can select the armature, shift select the mesh, go to weight paint mode and use Alt Click on a bone to select the relevant vertex group (Ctrl click on Blender versions older than 4.0)

[image]

Comment: I tried that, it highlights the bone but doesn't show me the weights.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have color overlays or do you mean that everything is dark blue? Or maybe you're dealing with a rig where control bones and deforming bones are not the same (like Rigify)?